# Averaging R2 between different sized test sets

Tags: cross-validation, r-squared

I'm testing a model using different tests sets. In fact, I'm mimicking cross validation but since my data is correlated I used data from individual years as test sets instead of assigning my data randomly to different test sets.

For each test set, I computed $R^2$ as:
$$R^2=1-\frac{\sum_i{(y_i-\hat{y_i})^2}}{\sum_i{(y_i-\bar{y_i})^2}}=1-\frac{RSS}{TSS}$$

Now I'm averaging those $R^2$ to get an average test $R^2$. As far as I know, the usual way of averaging $R^2$ is just to take the arithmetic mean across all train sets. However, my train sets are different sized because I have more cases from some years than other ones and years with more data should be given more weight.

My approach has been to sum squared residuals and total residuals across all test sets and sum total squares across all test sets and use them to compute $R^2$:

$$\bar{R^2} =1- \frac{\sum_{years}RSS_{year}}{\sum_{years}TSS_{year}}$$

I think my approach is reasonable but I'm concerned that I might be reinventing the wheel. Therefore my question is: Is there a standard way to average test $R^2$ across test sets of different size?

Comment: I'd suggest to calculate one single R-squared based on all hold-out residuals.

Comment: @MichaelM - If I'm understanding you well, that's what I'm doing. At least, I think my numerator is the sum of all squared hold-out residuals. However, I'm not sure about whether you propose a different denominator.

Comment: Right, except a "1 minus" in front of the ratio. If you calculate the TSS stratified by year (as you propose), it is like comparing the full model against a model with "year" as only factor, which makes perfect sense.